# Jquery is running my ziptastic slow

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my customers input their zip codes the output data (city and state) are loading so slow. They have to fill in the zip code extremely slow just so the data fields for city and state show up.  Any help would be great here is the function code from the site.

```
(function( $ ) {
    var requests = {};
    var zipValid = {
            us: /[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?/
    };

    $.ziptastic = function(zip, callback){
            // Only make unique requests
            if(!requests[zip]) {
                    requests[zip] = $.getJSON('http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com/v2/US/' + zip);
            }

            // Bind to the finished request
            requests[zip].done(function(data) {
                    callback(data.country, data.state, data.city, zip);
            });

            // Allow for binding to the deferred object
            return requests[zip];
    };

    $.fn.ziptastic = function( options ) {
            return this.each(function() {
                    var ele = $(this);

                    ele.on('keyup', function() {
                            var zip = ele.val();

                            // TODO Non-US zip codes?
                            if(zipValid.us.test(zip)) {
                                    $.ziptastic(zip, function(country, state, city) {
                                            // Trigger the updated information
                                            ele.trigger('zipChange', [country, state, city, zip]);
                                    })
                            }
                    });
            });
    };
})( jQuery );




    <?php
session_start();
include "include.php";

if(isset($_SESSION['memberID'])){
    $memberID = $_SESSION['memberID'];
    $factory = new TypeFactory($dbName);
    $o = $factory->get_object($memberID,"MEMBER");
}else{
    header("location:index.php");
}
// check if any order placed or not to get default address
    $sql12 = "select * from ORDERS where memberID =".$memberID." order by pickupDATE DESC";
    $res12 = getXbyY($sql12,"array");
    $row12 = count($res12);

    if($row12>2){
        if($res12[0]['f_countryID']!="" &&  $res12[0]['f_stateID']!="" &&  $res12[0]['f_cityID']!="" &&  $res12[0]['f_zipcode']!="" &&  $res12[0]['t_countryID']!="" && $res12[0]['t_stateID']!="" && $res12[0]['t_cityID'] && $res12[0]['t_zipcode']!=""){
            $default =1;
        }else{

        $default =0;
        }
    }
    if($o->memberID>0){
        $totalcarrier = gettotalmembercarrier($o->memberID);

    }


if(isset($_GET['msgID'])){
    $msgID = $_GET['msgID'];
}else{
    $msgID= 0;
}

$date1 = todayDateY();
$p1 = explode("-",$date1);
$year = $p1[0];
$month = $p1[1];
$date = $p1[2];
$value = $month."/".$date."/".$year;

$sql ="select * from MEMBER_CARRIER_LOGIN where memberID =".$_SESSION['memberID']." and isACTIVE = 1";
$res = getXbyY($sql,"array");
$row = count($res);


if($_POST['Submit'] == "Submit"){

    if($_POST['f_stateID'] =="" || $_POST['f_cityID'] =="" || $_POST['f_countryID'] == "" || $_POST['t_stateID'] =="" || $_POST['t_cityID'] =="" || $_POST['t_countryID'] == ""){
            header("location:calculator.php?msgID=175");
    }elseif($totalcarrier == 0){
            header("location:calculator.php");
    }else{
        $counter = 0;
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['shippingmode'] = $_POST['shippingmode'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['location'] = $_POST['location'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['ordername'] = $_POST['ordername'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['unit'] = $_POST['unit'];
            if($_SESSION['order'][$counter]['unit'] == 1){
                $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight_unit'] = "kg";
                $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['dimesions'] = "cm";
            }else{
                $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight_unit'] = "lb";
                $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['dimesions'] = "in";
            }   
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight'] = $_POST['weight'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['height'] = $_POST['height'];  
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['width'] = $_POST['width'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['len_gth'] = $_POST['len_gth'];    
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['shipmentID'] = $_POST['shipmentID'];  
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_address'] = $_POST['f_address'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_countryID'] = $_POST['f_countryID'];
        // to get country 
        /*if($_POST['f_countryID']!="" && $_POST['f_countryID'] >0){    
            $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_country'] = getcountryABBR($_POST['f_countryID']);
        }*/

        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_stateID'] = $_POST['f_stateID'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_cityID'] = $_POST['f_cityID'];

        if($_POST['isDEFAULT']!=""){
            $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_zipcode'] = $_POST['f_zipcode'];
        }else{
            $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_zipcode'] = $_POST['f_zipcode1'];
        }
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_address'] = $_POST['t_address'];    
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_countryID'] = $_POST['t_countryID'];
        /*if($_POST['t_countryID']!="" && $_POST['t_countryID'] >0){    
            $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_country'] = getcountryABBR($_POST['t_countryID']);
        } */


        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_stateID'] = $_POST['t_stateID'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_cityID'] = $_POST['t_cityID'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_zipcode'] = $_POST['t_zipcode'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['pickup'] = $_POST['datepicker'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['class'] = $_POST['class'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['role'] = $_POST['role'];
    /*  $p2 = explode("/",$dates);
        $month = $p2[0];
        $date = $p2[1];
        $year = $p2[2];
        $values = $month."-".$date."-".$year; */
        //$_SESSION['order'][$counter]['pickup'] = $dates;

        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['orderMADEON'] = todaysDate();

        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['senderNAME'] = $_POST['senderNAME'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['recipientNAME'] = $_POST['recipientNAME'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['isACTIVE'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['isDEFAULT'] = $_POST['isDEFAULT'];

        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_company'] = $res[0]['f_company'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_email'] = $res[0]['f_email'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_location'] = $res[0]['f_location'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_address'] = $res[0]['f_address'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_phonenumber'] = $res[0]['f_phonenumber'];


        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_company'] = $res[0]['t_company'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_email'] = $res[0]['t_email'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_location'] = $res[0]['t_location'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_address'] = $res[0]['t_address'];
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_phonenumber'] = $res[0]['t_phonenumber']; 


        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['senderNAME'] = $res[0]['senderNAME']; 
        $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['recipientNAME'] = $res[0]['recipientNAME']; 

            header("location:companies.php?rates=0");
        }
}

$msg= getERRORS($msgID);

include"includes/header.php";
include"html/calculator.php";
include"includes/footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: What's the bottleneck?  Is the HTTP request to the API taking a long time?  That's not really a problem with the code, that's the network connection.  Does the speed get faster with each successive keystroke producing a smaller result set?  If that's the case, you might delay the API call until 2-3 keystrokes have been entered.

Comment: #wordcrimes: it's only a "ZIP code" if you're in the US, elsewhere it's a "postal code" or some other name. @David: it appears to only look up complete ZIP codes, not partials.

Comment: yes the results start generating after keystrokes are bing done.  How can I delay the API call to something like 4 keystrokes

Comment: @blazemonger the city and state start to generate from 2 or more keystrokes

Comment: You need to show us that code, then. It looked to me like you were only running ziptastic when you have a valid ZIP code. `if(zipValid.us.test(zip))`

Comment: @Blazemonger i added the lines of code from the page.  If you would take a peak that would be great.  Thanks